# jQuery to update field onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

So I have a problem where I cannot for the life of me get a `jQuery` command to update a field on my html page.

The goal is when I open my navbar and see my elements, I want to update the brand text to show what 'page' i'm currently on.  The problem is, when I do a onClick event on any of those links, it does not update.  I can use the same code with a sample link on the main page and it works fine so I'm at a loss to what's causing this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid"><div class="navbar-brand" id="Brand">Brand</div><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" class="navbar-toggler"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" id="ONE">First Item</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Second Item</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Third Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#ONE').click(function() {
    $('#Brand').text('hello');
  });
});
```

Comment: This code works fine, the problem must be somewhere else.  Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?  When you debug, does this code execute at all?  Do the selectors find the elements you expect them to?  Are you re-using `id` values anywhere else on the page?

Comment: Nope, no errors or anything. It doesn't run. I've done a simple console log and it doesn't output if inside the clickI just made the ids up to test.  The bootstrap nav bar I'm using is the "better nav" and it causes the outside of the menu to lose focus and get dark. Maybe that is causing something

Comment: Try using `$(document).ready(function(){})` wrapping the jquery you have already

Comment: Are you sure it does not just reload the page? Your code is run imho (add a `console.log` to make sure) but it does not stop the default action.

Comment: 100% positive. I've opened the developer tools, looked at the page, see no refresh. I have a console.log now in the jquery and it outputs nothing. This is really odd.

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ONE').click(function() {
    $('#Brand').text('hello');
    console.log('hello');
  });
});

Comment: Ok so it's something with the better nav js that i'm using in conjunction with bootstrap 4.  If I remove this https://unpkg.com/@bootstrapstudio/bootstrap-better-nav/dist/bootstrap-better-nav.min.js, it works, with it in there, it fails *shrug*